# Processingでsplit関数で分割した文字列を、同じ文字列リテラルと等価演算子にかけるとfalseになる

Tags: java, processing

タイトル通りなのですが、以下がそのコードです。

```
String data = "iron/wood/gold";
String[] splitData = split(data, "/");
println(splitData[0] == "iron");
```

これを実行した結果がfalseになるのはなぜでしょうか。

Comment: Processing は使ってないないので見当違いなのかもしれませんが、javaで文字列の等値判定を行う場合は基本`equals`を使います。例：`splitData[0].equals("iron")`

Comment: ProcessingはJavaベースなので、同じ記述で解決しました。ありがとうございます。